# What is "Standard PS/2 Keyboard" in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

In device manager I see listed "Standard PS/2 Keyboard". But I don't even have a PS/2 port on my computer (HP Envy all-in-one).

Comment: Can you be more specific than "HP Envy all-in-one"?

Answer (score 2):

This will be a generic device name as inherited from it's parent. If you do View > Devices By Connection within device manager, you'll see it inherits from something like the below:

[image]